# 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to transfer data from the first page to the second page like this.

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (contex) => SegmentationSchedule(idBatch: batchTransfer.id!,)));
```

but when I try to retrieve the data a message like this appears

```
The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

this is how I display the data

```
class SegmentationSchedule extends StatefulWidget {
  int idBatch;
  SegmentationSchedule({super.key, required this.idBatch});
  @override
  State<SegmentationSchedule> createState() => _SegmentationScheduleState();
}

class _SegmentationScheduleState extends State<SegmentationSchedule> {
  int groupValue = 0;

  List<Widget> bodies = [
    DeliveryStatusDraft(id: widget.idBatch),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

```dart
List<Widget> bodies = [
  DeliveryStatusDraft(id: widget.idBatch),
];
```

You cannot access `widget` here. So what you could do is to create an empty array and initialize it in the `initState`.

```dart
List<Widget> bodies = [];

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  bodies = [
    DeliveryStatusDraft(id: widget.idBatch),
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SegmentationSchedule extends StatefulWidget {
  final int idBatch;
  const SegmentationSchedule({super.key, required this.idBatch});
  @override
  State<SegmentationSchedule> createState() => _SegmentationScheduleState();
}
```

In order to access member from constructor you should declare them as final so that you can use them as widget.idBatch. And use const keyword before your constructors.

If a value is immutable, that value cannot be changed. To make a field of a class immutable, you can use either the const or final keyword. If you use the const keyword, you need to initialize the value in the field declaration